# Merge in pandas over more columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following problem in pandas. I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'Name': ['c','c','c', 'a', 'a','b','b', 'z', 'y'], 'Project': ['aa','ab','bc', 'aa', 'ab','aa', 'ab','aa', 'ab'], 
     'col2': [3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 4]}

d1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

Separately I have this dataframe:

```
col = {'1': ['aa','ab','bc'], '2': ['aa', 'ab', None]  }

col = pd.DataFrame(data=col)
```

I would like to create a new column that add a column name from the *col* dataframe to each Name and Project in the *d1* above. Desired output is this:

```
d2 = {'Name': ['c','c','c', 'a', 'a','b','b', 'z', 'y'], 'Project': ['aa','ab','bc', 'aa', 'ab','aa', 'ab','aa', 'ab'], 
     'col2': [3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 4], 'Project_ID': ['1','1','1', '2', '2','2','2', None, None]}

d2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would something like this:

```
d1['Project_ID'] = None
for c in col.columns:
    d1.loc[d1['Project'].isin(col[c]), 'Project_ID'] = c
```

But since you have the same values in `col['1']` and `col['2']`, your desired output doesn't really make sense.